# What is PVFULL in Bitbake recipe

Tags: bitbake

Does anyone know what `PVFULL` does in Bitbake recipes? I have a build that used to work but is now broken so I'm trying to figure out what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's a custom proprietary parameter used alongside `PV` and `PR`:

```
inherit externalgitsrc

PV = "${EXTERNALSRC_GITPKGV}"
PR = "${EXTERNALSRC_GITPKGR}"
PVFULL = "${EXTERNALSRC_GITPKGVFULL}"
```